# Face of org-mode source block changes when returning from edit buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, faces

A strange thing happens when editing source blocks within an extra buffer with <kbd>C-c '</kbd>: the face of just this source block changes upon returning, i.e. the face settings are not used any more.

[image]

[image]

I'm using Emacs 25.1 with org-mode 8.2.10.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remedy this issue simply through upgrading org-mode to version 9.0.3. So there's probably a bug in 8.2.10.